# Query in HQL with multiple inputs for where clause

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Let's say I have the following query `"select myEntity where myEntityKey.value1= :value1 and myEntityKey.value2= :value2"`, and then let's say I have I receive multiple (value1, value2) pairs as input from a batch process, what is the best way to execute this query in bulk in a single go?

The existing code does something like this, and executes one query at a time:

```
for(MyEntityKey key : entitiesKeyList) {
  Record = 
   .getSessionFactory()
   .getCurrentSession()
   .createQuery(SELECT_MESSAGE_SQL)
   .setParameter(VALUE1_FIELD, key.getValue1())
   .setParameter(VALUE2_FIELD, key.getValue2())
   .getSingleResult();
   //do something with the result
}
```

How can I set all these parameter pairs in a single bulk query? I was considering to create a list for value1 and another list for value2 and use setParameterList but that means my where clause would become  `where myEntityKey.value1 IN (:value1) and myEntityKey.value2 IN (:value2)` and that may not work as expected since I want the each element to be used according to their position, for example myEntityKey.value1 = list1.get(i) and myEntityKey.value2 = list2.get(i). Maybe I just overthinking this and there is an easy way to achieve this.

Thank you.